# mkvirtualenv giving permission error for virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

When running `mkvirtualenv --python=python3.8 test` on my Mac terminal I get this permissions error:

> created virtual environment CPython3.8.2.final.0-64 in 545ms   creator
> CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/blake/.virtualenvs/test, clear=False,
> global=False)   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest,
> setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy,
> app_data_dir=/Users/blake/Library/Application
> Support/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)   activators
> BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
> virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied:
> /Users/blake/Library/Python/3.8/

I'm able to import the virtualenvwrapper module directly in Python 3.8 so I know I have it installed correctly, it just doesn't allow me to create the virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like reinstalling virtualenvwrapper and putting `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3` in .bash_profile resolved the issue.